# Flattening deeply nested JSON into pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, nested, json-normalize, json-flattener

I am trying to import a deeply nested JSON into pandas dataframe. Here is the structure of the JSON file (this is only the first record (retweets[:1]):

```
[{'lang': 'en',
  'author_id': '1076979440372965377',
  'reply_settings': 'everyone',
  'entities': {'mentions': [{'start': 3,
     'end': 17,
     'username': 'Terry81987010',
     'url': '',
     'location': 'Florida',
     'entities': {'description': {'hashtags': [{'start': 29,
         'end': 32,
         'tag': '2A'}]}},
     'created_at': '2019-02-01T23:01:11.000Z',
     'protected': False,
     'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 520,
      'following_count': 567,
      'tweet_count': 34376,
      'listed_count': 1},
     'name': "Terry's Take",
     'verified': False,
     'id': '1091471553437593605',
     'description': 'Less government more Freedom #2A is a constitutional right. Trump2020, common sense rules, God bless America! Vet 82nd Airborne F/A, proud Republican',
     'profile_image_url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1289626661911134208/WfztLkr1_normal.jpg'},
    {'start': 19,
     'end': 32,
     'username': 'DineshDSouza',
     'location': 'United States',
     'entities': {'url': {'urls': [{'start': 0,
         'end': 23,
         'expanded_url': 'https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-dinesh-dsouza-podcast/id1547827376',
         'display_url': 'podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the…'}]},
      'description': {'urls': [{'start': 80,
         'end': 103,
         'expanded_url': 'https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-dinesh-dsouza-podcast/id1547827376',
         'display_url': 'podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the…'}]}},
     'created_at': '2009-11-22T22:32:41.000Z',
     'protected': False,
     'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 1748832,
      'following_count': 5355,
      'tweet_count': 65674,
      'listed_count': 6966},
     'name': "Dinesh D'Souza",
     'verified': True,
     'pinned_tweet_id': '1393309917239562241',
     'id': '91882544',
     'description': "I am an author, filmmaker, and host of the Dinesh D'Souza Podcast.\n\nSubscribe: ",
     'profile_image_url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/890967538292711424/8puyFbiI_normal.jpg'}]},
  'conversation_id': '1253462541881106433',
  'created_at': '2020-04-23T23:15:32.000Z',
  'id': '1253462541881106433',
  'possibly_sensitive': False,
  'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'retweeted',
    'id': '1253052684489437184',
    'in_reply_to_user_id': '91882544',
    'attachments': {'media_keys': ['3_1253052312144293888',
      '3_1253052620937277442'],
     'media': [{}, {}]},
    'entities': {'annotations': [{'start': 126,
       'end': 128,
       'probability': 0.514,
       'type': 'Organization',
       'normalized_text': 'CDC'},
      {'start': 145,
       'end': 146,
       'probability': 0.5139,
       'type': 'Place',
       'normalized_text': 'NY'}],
     'mentions': [{'start': 0,
       'end': 13,
       'username': 'DineshDSouza',
       'location': 'United States',
       'entities': {'url': {'urls': [{'start': 0,
           'end': 23,
           'expanded_url': 'https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-dinesh-dsouza-podcast/id1547827376',
           'display_url': 'podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the…'}]},
        'description': {'urls': [{'start': 80,
           'end': 103,
           'expanded_url': 'https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-dinesh-dsouza-podcast/id1547827376',
           'display_url': 'podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the…'}]}},
       'created_at': '2009-11-22T22:32:41.000Z',
       'protected': False,
       'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 1748832,
        'following_count': 5355,
        'tweet_count': 65674,
        'listed_count': 6966},
       'name': "Dinesh D'Souza",
       'verified': True,
       'pinned_tweet_id': '1393309917239562241',
       'id': '91882544',
       'description': "I am an author, filmmaker, and host of the Dinesh D'Souza Podcast.\n\nSubscribe:  ",
       'profile_image_url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/890967538292711424/8puyFbiI_normal.jpg'}],
     'urls': [{'start': 187,
       'end': 210,
       'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/Terry81987010/status/1253052684489437184/photo/1',
       'display_url': 'pic.twitter.com/H4NpN5ZMkW'},
      {'start': 187,
       'end': 210,
       'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/Terry81987010/status/1253052684489437184/photo/1',
       'display_url': 'pic.twitter.com/H4NpN5ZMkW'}]},
    'lang': 'en',
    'author_id': '1091471553437593605',
    'reply_settings': 'everyone',
    'conversation_id': '1253050942716551168',
    'created_at': '2020-04-22T20:06:55.000Z',
    'possibly_sensitive': False,
    'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'replied_to', 'id': '1253050942716551168'}],
    'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 208,
     'reply_count': 57,
     'like_count': 402,
     'quote_count': 38},
    'source': 'Twitter Web App',
    'text': "@DineshDSouza Here's some proof of artificially inflating the cv deaths. Noone is dying of pneumonia anymore according to the CDC. And of course NY getting paid for each cv death $60,000",
    'context_annotations': [{'domain': {'id': '10',
       'name': 'Person',
       'description': 'Named people in the world like Nelson Mandela'},
      'entity': {'id': '1138120064119369729', 'name': "Dinesh D'Souza"}},
     {'domain': {'id': '35',
       'name': 'Politician',
       'description': 'Politicians in the world, like Joe Biden'},
      'entity': {'id': '1138120064119369729', 'name': "Dinesh D'Souza"}}],
    'author': {'url': '',
     'username': 'Terry81987010',
     'location': 'Florida',
     'entities': {'description': {'hashtags': [{'start': 29,
         'end': 32,
         'tag': '2A'}]}},
     'created_at': '2019-02-01T23:01:11.000Z',
     'protected': False,
     'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 520,
      'following_count': 567,
      'tweet_count': 34376,
      'listed_count': 1},
     'name': "Terry's Take",
     'verified': False,
     'id': '1091471553437593605',
     'description': 'Less government more Freedom #2A is a constitutional right. Trump2020, common sense rules, God bless America! Vet 82nd Airborne F/A, proud Republican',
     'profile_image_url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1289626661911134208/WfztLkr1_normal.jpg'},
    'in_reply_to_user': {'username': 'DineshDSouza',
     'location': 'United States',
     'entities': {'url': {'urls': [{'start': 0,
         'end': 23,
         'expanded_url': 'https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-dinesh-dsouza-podcast/id1547827376',
         'display_url': 'podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the…'}]},
      'description': {'urls': [{'start': 80,
         'end': 103,
         'expanded_url': 'https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-dinesh-dsouza-podcast/id1547827376',
         'display_url': 'podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the…'}]}},
     'created_at': '2009-11-22T22:32:41.000Z',
     'protected': False,
     'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 1748832,
      'following_count': 5355,
      'tweet_count': 65674,
      'listed_count': 6966},
     'name': "Dinesh D'Souza",
     'verified': True,
     'pinned_tweet_id': '1393309917239562241',
     'id': '91882544',
     'description': "I am an author, filmmaker, and host of the Dinesh D'Souza Podcast.\n\nSubscribe:  ",
     'profile_image_url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/890967538292711424/8puyFbiI_normal.jpg'}}],
  'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 208,
   'reply_count': 0,
   'like_count': 0,
   'quote_count': 0},
  'source': 'Twitter for iPhone',
  'text': "RT @Terry81987010: @DineshDSouza Here's some proof of artificially inflating the cv deaths. Noone is dying of pneumonia anymore according t…",
  'context_annotations': [{'domain': {'id': '10',
     'name': 'Person',
     'description': 'Named people in the world like Nelson Mandela'},
    'entity': {'id': '1138120064119369729', 'name': "Dinesh D'Souza"}},
   {'domain': {'id': '35',
     'name': 'Politician',
     'description': 'Politicians in the world, like Joe Biden'},
    'entity': {'id': '1138120064119369729', 'name': "Dinesh D'Souza"}}],
  'author': {'url': '',
   'username': 'set1952',
   'location': 'Etats-Unis',
   'created_at': '2018-12-23T23:14:42.000Z',
   'protected': False,
   'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 103,
    'following_count': 44,
    'tweet_count': 44803,
    'listed_count': 0},
   'name': 'SunSet1952',
   'verified': False,
   'id': '1076979440372965377',
   'description': '',
   'profile_image_url': 'https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png'},
  '__twarc': {'url': 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/all?expansions=author_id%2Cin_reply_to_user_id%2Creferenced_tweets.id%2Creferenced_tweets.id.author_id%2Centities.mentions.username%2Cattachments.poll_ids%2Cattachments.media_keys%2Cgeo.place_id&user.fields=created_at%2Cdescription%2Centities%2Cid%2Clocation%2Cname%2Cpinned_tweet_id%2Cprofile_image_url%2Cprotected%2Cpublic_metrics%2Curl%2Cusername%2Cverified%2Cwithheld&tweet.fields=attachments%2Cauthor_id%2Ccontext_annotations%2Cconversation_id%2Ccreated_at%2Centities%2Cgeo%2Cid%2Cin_reply_to_user_id%2Clang%2Cpublic_metrics%2Ctext%2Cpossibly_sensitive%2Creferenced_tweets%2Creply_settings%2Csource%2Cwithheld&media.fields=duration_ms%2Cheight%2Cmedia_key%2Cpreview_image_url%2Ctype%2Curl%2Cwidth%2Cpublic_metrics&poll.fields=duration_minutes%2Cend_datetime%2Cid%2Coptions%2Cvoting_status&place.fields=contained_within%2Ccountry%2Ccountry_code%2Cfull_name%2Cgeo%2Cid%2Cname%2Cplace_type&max_results=500&query=retweets_of%3ATerry81987010&start_time=2020-03-09T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00&end_time=2020-04-24T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00',
   'version': '2.0.8',
   'retrieved_at': '2021-05-17T17:13:17+00:00'}},
```

Here is my code:

```
retweets = []
for line in open('Data/usersRetweetsFlatten_sample.json', 'r'):
    retweets.append(json.loads(line))

df = json_normalize(
    retweets, 'referenced_tweets', ['referenced_tweets', 'type'],
    meta_prefix= ".",
    errors='ignore'
)
df[['author_id',  'type', '.type', 'id', 'in_reply_to_user_id', 'referenced_tweets']].head()
```

Here is the resulting dataframe:

[image]

As you can see, the column `referenced_tweets` is not flattened yet (please note that there are two different `referenced_tweets` arrays in my JSON file: one is in a deeper level insdide the other "referenced_tweets"). For example, the one at the higher level return this:

```
 >>> retweets[0]["referenced_tweets"][0]["type"]
"retweeted"
```

and the one in the deeper level return this:

```
>>> retweets[0]["referenced_tweets"][0]["referenced_tweets"][0]["type"]
'replied_to'
```

**QUESTION:** I was wondering how I can flatten the deeper `referenced_tweets`. I want to have two separate columns as `referenced_tweets.type` and `referenced_tweets.id`, where the value of the column `referenced_tweets.type` in the above example should be `replied_to`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that your data is double nested... there is a key `referenced_tweets` within `referenced_tweets`.

```py
import json
from pandas import json_normalize

with open("flatten.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

df = json_normalize(
    data, 
    record_path=["referenced_tweets", "referenced_tweets"],
    meta=[
        "author_id",
        
        # ["author", "username"], # not possible
        # "author", # possible but not useful
        
        ["referenced_tweets", "id"],
        ["referenced_tweets", "type"],
        ["referenced_tweets", "in_reply_to_user_id"],
        ["referenced_tweets", "in_reply_to_user", "username"], 
    ]
)

print(df)
```

[image]

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37668569/42659

---

**Note:** Above code will fail if second nested `referenced_tweet` is missing.

---

**Edit:** Alternatively you could further normalize your data (which you already partly normalized with your code) in your question with an additional manual iteration. See example below. Note: Code is not optimized and may be slow depending on the amount of data.

```py
# load your `data` with `json.load()` or `json.loads()`

df = json_normalize(
    data, 
    record_path="referenced_tweets",
    meta=["referenced_tweets", "type"],
    meta_prefix= ".",
    errors="ignore",
)

columns = [*df.columns, "_type", "_id"]
normalized_data = []

def append(row, type, id):
    normalized_row = [*row.to_list(), type, id]
    normalized_data.append(normalized_row)

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    
    # a list/array is expected
    if type(row["referenced_tweets"]) is list:
        for tweet in row["referenced_tweets"]:
            append(row, tweet["type"], tweet["id"])
        # if empty list
        else:
            append(row, None, None)
    else:
        append(row, None, None)

enhanced_df = pd.DataFrame(data=normalized_data, columns=columns)
enhanced_df.drop("referenced_tweets", 1)

print(enhanced_df)
```

[image]

---

**Edit 2:** `referenced_tweets` should be an array. However, if there is no referenced tweet, the Twitter API seems to omit `referenced_tweets` completely. In that case, the cell value is `NaN` (float) instead of an empty list. I updated the code above to take that into account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your code, but I get this error: `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 9030)`. I think maybe because of using `json.load`? (I mean maybe I should try with reading/loading line by line)

Comment: I tried with this: `retweets = []
for line in open('Data/usersRetweetsFlatten_sample.json', 'r'):
    retweets.append(json.loads(line))`, but I still get the error: `KeyError: 'referenced_tweets'`

Comment: Looks like you have multiple JSON object (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21058946/42659) in your file. I was not aware of that. Unless I have some data to reproduce your issue, I am not able to help you. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple json objects in my file. Thanks for sharing the link. If you check out the code I posted in my question, I already used the same method and I have no issues in importing the json file into pandas dataframe. The problem is how to access deeper levels of the nested json.

Comment: I don't think it should not make a difference. I just dumped your example from above in a JSON file. My guess is that you have 1 record which may not have a second nested reference_tweet. If I remove it in my sample JSON file based on your example, then I get the same KeyError. The code seems to work if the second nested key reference_tweet is around with records and as well as an empty array but not if the key is missing. -- Your JSON may have too many branches to get a somehow useful result with `json_normalize`.

Comment: You may have to transform your data in more than one iteration. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your new update. I tried your code, but it gives me this error: `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`. The error is related to this line of code: `for tweet in row["referenced_tweets"]:`. Also, I tried the first piece of your updated code (only `df = json_normalize(data,  record_path="referenced_tweets", meta=["referenced_tweets", "type"],...`) and it works (I mean it gives me the columns that I want, except that it doesn't extract the `type` and `id` from the more nested referenced_tweets)

Comment: Sorry, if I didn't accept it as an answer because it didn't answer my question yet. But I upvoted your answer because of your help and the time you spent. Thank you!

Comment: See my second edit. The issue is that `referenced_tweet` is omitted by the Twitter API if there are no entries. That's why you got `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`. I hope this solves your issue. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your edit. It works :) There was just one extra `else` in your code (`the inner else is extra`) that I removed because it added many extra rows to my dataframe. Thank you again!